# dash over a letter

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I write a letter like : A ,with a bar over it ( stands for the closure of A in topology) . I looked it up but \={A} didn't work , see : $\={A}$ .Help

Comment: For single letter, you can use `\bar` ( eg, `\bar{A}` $\to \bar{A}$). For putting a line over multiple letters, use `\overline` instead (e.g. `\overline{ABC}` $\to \overline{ABC}$).

Comment: See the apt discussion of such [accents and diacritical marks](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in Section 14 of the Question body for MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference, a good place for seeking similar tips and techniques.

Comment: I'm curious as to where the `\=` idea came from...

Comment: Text symbols ! ,short list (item 12

Answer (score 4):

> \overline{A}

reads as

$$\overline{A}$$

Comment: works also without the brackets: `\overline A`

Comment: Thanks for the help